# Write every vector as sum of vectors from these subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

$$S = \{(x_1, x_2, ...,x_n)^T~|~ x_1+2x_2+3x_3+...+nx_n=0 \}$$

$$T = \{(x_1, x_2, ...,x_n)^T~|~ x_1=x_2=x_3=...=x_n \}$$

$R^n$ is a direct sum of $S$ and $T$. This follows from Grassmann formula:

$\dim S + \dim T = \dim(S\cap T) + \dim(S + T)$

In other words every vector $v\in$  $R^n$ can be written as $v=s+t$, where $s\in S, t \in T$.

Writing out the canonical basis is sufficient. For example :

$$(1,0,0,...,0)=t+s$$

Can someone help me find $s$ and $t$ .

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You are right, the latter condition simply becomes void.

Comment: In terms of the usual definitions, it is not  correct to say that "$S$ and $T$ are a direct sum of $\Bbb R^n$".  If you mean to say that $S + T = \Bbb R$, then you could say that $\Bbb R^n$ is the sum of $S$ and $T$; note that it is not a direct sum because $\dim(S \cap T) \neq 0.$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $\dim(S∩T)$ is $0$. The only vector in both $S$ and $T$ is the zero vector.

Comment: @Milan whoops, you're right; I made a silly mistake there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=4$, then:

- $\displaystyle(1,0,0,0)=\overbrace{\left(\frac9{10},-\frac1{10},-\frac1{10},-\frac1{10}\right)}^{\phantom S\in S}+\overbrace{\left(\frac1{10},\frac1{10},\frac1{10},\frac1{10}\right)}^{\phantom T\in T}$;
- $\displaystyle(0,1,0,0)=\overbrace{\left(-\frac2{10},\frac8{10},-\frac2{10},-\frac2{10}\right)}^{\phantom S\in S}+\overbrace{\left(\frac2{10},\frac2{10},\frac2{10},\frac2{10}\right)}^{\phantom T\in T}$
- $\displaystyle(0,0,1,0)=\overbrace{\left(-\frac3{10},-\frac3{10},\frac7{10},-\frac3{10}\right)}^{\phantom S\in S}+\overbrace{\left(\frac3{10},\frac3{10},\frac3{10},\frac3{10}\right)}^{\phantom T\in T}$
- $\displaystyle(0,0,0,1)=\overbrace{\left(-\frac4{10},-\frac4{10},-\frac4{10},\frac6{10}\right)}^{\phantom S\in S}+\overbrace{\left(\frac4{10},\frac4{10},\frac4{10},\frac4{10}\right)}^{\phantom T\in T}$.

Can you deal with the general case now?